# Connecting two separate services

Tags: electrical-panel

I hope this make sense. My home used to be a church that was converted to a duplex. We turned it into a single family residence.

Both sides have their own power service from our local electric company. As it is now, the well pump and 1 water heater is on side and the kitchen was removed. Side 2 has an electric stove, microwave
washer and dryer (as far as big appliances go).

This is what I plan on doing and need some advice and opinions on how to go about this. Since the fee for having the privilege of power from company is about $40, I want to disconnect #2 service and connect #2 breaker box to #1 breaker box, and discontinue service to #2.

Both services have each have a meter and a main breaker outside with a breaker panel on the respective sides. I plan on digging out a basement for a shop and will at some point take the #2 service to power the shop and shop related tools, ie. welder, plasma cutter, air compressor etc, that is unless there is a way to add this 3rd area to the #1 panel. I will be replacing both #1 and 2 breaker panels this summer since they area woefully too small all ready and I will be connecting a back up generator to #1 since my remote location has regular power outages. I do have plans for getting off the power grid entirely, but that is down the road a few years, but having 1 breaker box would make it easier.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: If both panels are about 200 amps each, you probably have enough power size.  Might be a problem if they undersize both panels/meters/service wires, and you probably will need to upgrade the service wires and transformer/s.  Most of the rest is just work changing the circuits, having one main panel and one sub panel, or just get one big main.

Comment: It will depend on the rating of the meters you have now, .vs. the loads you have now or plan to have later. You may need to replace the meter base and get a new, single, larger meter from the power company, which may involve other costs from the power company, or not, depending what they are running there now and/or if what they are willing to keep providing service to is different than what they are willing to do for an upgraded/new service. Matters where in the world and/or what state your remote location is in for applicable codes, and who your power company is. [Edit] to provide details.

Comment: If you intend to replace #1 and feed #2 from it and also intend to replace #2, you should just replace #1 with the biggest one you can get (breaker-spaces) unless you need more amps than that supports. Which gets back to details. Adding pictures of the panels and meter/mains is also helpful, since some folks will see things you don't think to describe in text.

Comment: First, make sure that's going to work.  Many companies charge you for the right to have service there, they'll cheerfully remove the wires but the charge will not go away.  So ask them if eliminating the second service will actually remove the charge. What is the Article 220 Load Calculation for each service?

Comment: Who is your electric utility?